# JS: Make a callback return the output of another callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, magicsuggest

I am using the Javascript [magicsuggest plugin](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest).

This plugin has a callback `selectionRenderer` that allows you to change the html of a selection before it's inserted.

What I'm trying to do, is to change that selection html based on user input.

So the way I have it setup, the `selectionRenderer` callback opens a Bootstrap modal which has a form inside it. Then another `submit` callback is created for when that form is submitted.

I can't figure out how to pass the data that is collected in the `submit` callback into that `selectionRenderer` callback.

```
$(function() {

  var modal = $('#exampleModal');

  $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
    selectionRenderer: function(data){
      modal.modal('show');

      var color = 'red';
      modal.find('#color-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        color = $(this).find('#color-input').val();
        console.log(color);

        modal.modal('hide');
      });

      return '<span style="color: '+color+';">' + data.name + '</span>';
    },
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    data: data
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsnues19/9/)

As you can see, the `color` in this example is collected in the `submit` callback, but since that callback is fired asynchronously, there is no way to pass that data to the `selectionRenderer` callback, because that function has already returned.

In a perfect world I could obviously just make the code stop and wait for a callback to continue, but since it's a plugin I'd rather not fork and butcher it.

Comment: that's... not possible. and doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You wanted to return the value of an input, after a form has submitted, from a function that defines the submit event?

Comment: *"In a perfect world I could obviously just make the code stop and wait for a callback to continue"* erm. well, i mean, no, you can't really do that in javascript period.

Comment: Why don't you just set the color of the span in the modal callback?

Comment: @KevinB It is possible with ES6 using the yield keyword. I just want another way because it's not well supported yet.

Comment: @Nikita240 eh, no, that's not the same thing. You can pause logic within a generator or an async function, but that won't make your code work, you'd still need to work with the async nature of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event that opens the modal to the selection event and in the submit handler  look for the last tag to change it's color

```
 var ms = $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
    selectionRenderer: function(data) { 
      return '<span class="my-tags">' + data.name + '</span>';
    },
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    data: data
  })

  $(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e, m) {
    modal.modal('show');
  });;

  $('#color-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var color = $('#color-input').val();
    $('.my-tags:last').css('color', color);   
    modal.modal('hide');
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lhzjwr9/1)**</kbd>